# HELP CiviDiscount Auto-Apply feature not working!

Tags: cividiscount

I'm using cividiscount 3.3 on civicrm 4.7.16 on Joomla 3.6.5. I created a discount code for current members to be applied automatically only it does not apply automatically. I can enter it manually. I've attached the code configuration, can anybody tell me what might be wrong? By the way I reviewed similar posts and some of the older posts are describing a patch but I'm thinking it was resolved in the latest version, 3.3? If not can someone please help?

Thanks[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJGXt.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. Users need to log in to Joomla to get the discount.

Comment: Thanks for posting this.  I'm glad you managed to sort it out.  Do you want to mark it as the accepted answer to this question?

Comment: Yes, how do I mark it as accepted?

Comment: You should be able to click on a tick next to the answer to mark it as accepted

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue.

A discount code is created for each membership levels. It doesn't apply on the event types but applies if you select an event in the Events field so each time you create a new event, you have to remember to associate the automatic discount code to the new event.

It is a workaround but it would be great to have it working.